# Require Suggestions, new to c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am required to create a data structure and I have so far created a simple table consisting of 4 different vectors that represent  variable. variable type, bool result and PKB output. I know that it is not the best way to do it but I was planning to insert and retrieve using index. However, I encounter a problem with Query ID because I am expecting to use getMethods to retrieve the information. I need to find a way to retrieve the information much more smoothly than to run through by index. The retrieval process will be by batch of Query ID.

I am new to Cplusplus and I am not sure what data structure or how I can solve it. I am not expecting a direct answer but a suggestion would suffice. Names that I probably never heard before. It would be best if you have a step by step guide.

---Query ID ---- Variable --- Variable Type --- bool result---- PKB output

----   1    -------------------   x     -----  assignment  ----------- true      ----------- null
-------------------------------------------------   1    -------------------    w     ----------     while    -------------- false      ---------- null
-------------------------------------------------   1    ------------------    ifstat-----------      if     ------------- ----false     ---- ----- null
------------------------------------------------   2    -------------------    x     ------  assignment  ----------- false     ---------- null --------------------------------------------

Comment: If you want to find some data for a specific query id, you need to either have an array (in the computing science sense) indexed by that id, or use an associative container.  C++ provides `std::vector` for flexibly sized array management, and you can use `std::map` as a general purpose associative container.  "best if you have a step by step guide" - you can search for a tutorial on those Standard Library types and how to use them, it's too much to detail in a S.O. answer, and requests for off-site resources are off-topic.

Comment: What is that diagram supposed to be? Please post it in a readable format. Paste the formatted diagram, mark it with the mouse, and click on the `{ }` tool or type Ctl-k to mark it as literal code.

Comment: `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` seems to be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand reading your question, You can use a `std::multimap` using `int` and `struct`. For instance

```
// C++11 for nullptr
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct Data {
    std::string variable;
    std::string variableType;
    bool        result;
    PKB         output;    // I suppose PKB is an already defined type

    Data(std::string var, std::string varType, bool res = false, PKB out = nullptr) :
        variable(var), variableType(varType), result(res), output(out) {}

    inline bool operator <(const Data & rhs) {
        . . .    // Add your own comparison logic
    }
};

std::multimap<int, Data> myMap;
myMap.insert((1, Data("x", "assignment", true)));
myMap.insert((1, Data("w", "while")));
myMap.insert((1, Data("ifstat", "if")));
myMap.insert((2, Data("x", "assignment")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand the question completely. But I think your using the standard library that contains the def of a vector, meaning you would have to use the getters and setters of that std. I would just make a function with a quick search algorithm that uses the getter already defined in the vector.